# Is there any way to go back a step in a Python for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I wish to find a way to efficiently imitate the same possible behaviour from the `while` loops to the `for` loops, to make the loop "stall" or go back a step if a condition is met. The reason for this is that I'm trying to implement a calculation with a big number of iterations, and the `for` looping is 4x faster than the `while` looping, according to `%%timeit`.

```
%%timeit
n = 0
while n < 1e7:
    n += 1
# 1.96 s +- 211 ms per loop

%%timeit
for i in range(int(1e7)):
    pass
# 399 ms +- 28.1 ms per loop
```

To those mentioning how this is an "unfair" comparison, the `while` loop cannot loop without the `n += 1` statement, while the `for` loop can. So that line is *necessary* for the while-loop and *unnecessary* for the for-loop, thus it's not an "unfair" comparison.

My specific problem/code:

```
def euler_differentiate_mod(w, bounds = None, delta = 1e-3, itern = 1e3,
    force = False,
    tols = [10, 0.1], step_mults = [0.1, 10]):

    if bounds is None:
        bounds = [0]*len(w)

    if not force and itern >= 1e9:
        raise OverflowError("number of iterations is too big: {!s}" + "\n" + \
            "you can ignore this error by setting the `force` kwarg to `False`"
            .format(itern))

    itern = int(itern)

    var = bounds

    n = 1
    while n < itern: # used to be: for n in range(1, itern+1):

        pvar = copy.deepcopy(var)

        for i,_ in enumerate(var): # compute new variables
            var[i] += w[i](*[delta]+[pvar[j] for j in range(len(pvar))])

        fchanges = [abs(var[i]-pvar[i]) for i in range(1, len(var))]

        try:
            if len(check) > 2:
                n += 1
        except:
            check = []

        if max(fchanges) > tols[0]: # big change -> reduce delta
            try:
                check.append(n)
            except:
                check = []
            delta *= step_mults[0] if delta <= 1 else 1

        elif max(fchanges) < tols[1]: # small change -> increase delta
            try:
                check.append(n)
            except:
                check = []
            delta *= step_mults[1] if delta <= 1 else 1

        else:
            check = False
            n += 1

    return None
```

Comment: You cannot go "back" a step. But maybe a bit of code would give a hint of what could be done? :)

Comment: "for looping is 4x faster than the while looping" That's an interesting statement. Can you please share more info (maybe even some code) about that observation?

Comment: Why you say `for` looping is 4x faster than the `while`?

Comment: 4x faster, according to `%%timeit`. Also, I'm trying to implement a calculation for [variable-step integration](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0307904X76900342), so the only method I see so far to accomplish this is using a `while` loop.

Comment: I also do not understand the downvotes, this being a legitimate question with a fair purpose and some research behind it.

Comment: That is not a valid comparison, you are comparing a loop that has to do an operation and one that isn't. you should create a complete [mcve]

Comment: @Sayse well, that is exactly what I'm trying to prove. I don't need the operation if it's not to make the loop go backwards, which is the possibility the `while` loop offers. Please think some more before labeling questions as "lazy".

Comment: This is a [http://xyproblem.info] (X,Y problem). You think you need to "go back a step" in a loop, but you do not. Also your reason (for loops are 4x faster than while loops) is wrong. You also didn't post any code. The added wrong, unrelated code you did post is of an image!

Comment: I never said your question was lazy, I'm saying that it isn't based on a valid test case. simply add in a `n=0` and `n += 1` inside the for loop rather than the `pass` (as a start)

Comment: @Sayse I don't need to add a `n += 1` inside the loop for my actual code, that would be just irrelevant code. However, if I do the `while` loop I indeed need to do the operation, which is maybe part of why one loop is faster than the other.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: @dustytrash if I had to post a code I would have to post a whole function of a hundred lines, which I'm not going to do. Posting less would also make no sense. So I simply post a proof of the different loops doing their jobs in different time spans, which is the reason I am posing my problem in the first place.

Comment: Right.  However, note that this is merely in the overhead of the loop maintenance.  Once you have an actual loop body, the difference of ~7ms per loop will almost certainly disappear into the noise of your purposeful operations.

Comment: @Prune 4x as fast, not just 7ms (actually 120ms in that example, and scales linearly with the number of iterations). The actual code has more than `1e6` iterations, as I said (up to `1e9`). It's a big calculation, so that difference ends up being very noticeable. The question is well fundamented, I suggest stop trying to nitpick. I changed the example to show `1e7` iterations, so you can expect what happens at `1e9` or greater.

Comment: "I need to go back in a for-loop so I can imitate while-loops since while-loops are much faster". You've probably written this question in the best way possible, but it's still a rather silly question.

Comment: @dustytrash not if you consider the time issue I think I properly explained in my last comment to Martijn's answer.

Comment: I downvoted because its unclear what problem you're trying to solve, you've only mentioned what you hope to be a solution to an issue that as explained previously is based off false pretences. If you wish to discuss the reason for downvotes further you should ask a question on [meta].

Comment: @Sayse `while` loops needing a `n += 1` line to work is not a false pretence as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Roelant added code.

Comment: It's a little late now to pivot this to your actual euler code (which could do with slimming down, we don't need to have the plotting code in there). The obvious problem that I see is the `copy.deepcopy()` call in it, which will far outweigh the cost of replacing `for` with `while`. You don't even need it, just create a new empty list from `[f(delta, *var) for f in w]`. Your `while` loop can be replaced with a nested loop, you never go back, only forward, but repeat the loop body 1 or more times.

Comment: You can cut out those repeated `max()` calls too. And set `changes = []` when resetting, not `False`, so you can remove the `try...except` blocks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters to your first comment, first part: thank you. Second part: yes, that's why I asked about "stalling" as well as going back in the body of the question. Also, I will take a look on how to implement what you're saying in that second part and your other comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for` loops don't go back or forth. They simply take the [iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) for a given [iterable object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), then repeatedly call the [`__next__()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) until that method raises `StopIteration`.

For sequence objects, the iterator simply keeps an internal index that's incremented each time `__next__` is called to get the next value in the sequence. That internal index is usually not accessible.

So if your specific use case is made easier by 'going back', you'd have to create an iterator object that exposes the index, or otherwise lets you alter what value is going to be produced for the next `__next__` call:

```
class PositionableSequenceIterator:
    def __init__(self, sequence):
        self.seq = sequence
        self._nextpos = None

    @property
    def pos(self):
        pos = self._nextpos
        return 0 if pos is None else pos - 1

    @pos.setter
    def pos(self, newpos):
        if not 0 <= newpos < len(self.seq):
            raise IndexError(newpos)
        self._nextpos = newpos

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            return self.seq[self.nextpos or 0]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        finally:
            self.nextpos += 1
```

so now you can do

```
iterator = PositionableSequenceIterator(some_list)
for elem in iterator:
    if somecondition:
        iterator.pos -= 2
    # ...
```

to skip back two steps.

I'd not expect this to be faster than a `while` loop, however. `while` loops are not specifically faster, testing the `while` condition each iteration is not much different from calling `iterator.__next__()`, really. In your timed test, the `while` condition is slower because it executes Python bytecode each iteration (both for the condition *and* to increment `n` in the loop body), but the `range()` iterator is implemented entirely in C. The iterator class above implements `__next__` in Python code again, so will be **just as slow**.

To demonstrate, I can show you that the timing differences are entirely due to the condition and loop body being slower:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer("n = 0\nwhile n < 10 ** 6:\n    n += 1").autorange()
>>> whileloop = total / count
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer("for i in range(10 ** 6):\n    pass").autorange()
>>> forloop = total / count
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer("n < 10 ** 6", "n = 10 ** 5 * 5").autorange()
>>> testbelow = total / count
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer("n += 1", "n = 0").autorange()
>>> increment = total / count
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer("nxt()", "nxt = iter(range(1 << 23)).__next__").autorange()  # enough room to find a good test range
>>> rangeitnext = total / count
>>> whileloop - forloop  # the for loop "speed advantage", per million iterations
0.03363728789991001
>>> (testbelow + increment) - rangeitnext  # relative difference per iteration
-9.191804809961469e-08
>>> ((testbelow + increment) - rangeitnext) * 10 ** 9  # microseconds
-91.9180480996147
```

So in these tests I can at best prove that there's only 92 *microseconds* between each loop iteration step, with `while` *faster*, if that makes any sense. That's because if I repeat this often enough, it'll *about* hit the `(whileloop - forloop) / 10 ** 6` difference, because these numbers are just way too small to really care about.

Note that an iterator like the above is usually overkill. The vast majority of problems where someone might wish to "rewind" an iterator really just want to keep track of previously seen items. You can trivially do that with other options too, like a queue:

```
from collections import deque

preceding = deque(maxlen=2)
for item in iterable:
    if condition:
        # process items in preceding

    preceding.append(item)
```

The above keeps the last two items seen around in case you need to process those.

Or you could use `zip()` and independent iterators:

```
from itertools import islice

twoforward = islice(iterable, 2, None)
for twoback, current in zip(iterable, twoforward):
    # twoback and current are paired up at indices i - 2 and i.
```

As for your `euler_differentiate_mod()` function, the following achieves the same work, without the need to advance a `while` counter. Your function basically calculates deltas up to 3 times per iteration, and moves to the next iteration when you either have a maximum change within toleration bounds or you tried 3 times:

```
def euler_differentiate_mod(
    w, bounds=None, delta=1e-3, itern=1000, tols=(10, 0.1), step_mults=(0.1, 10)
):
    if bounds is None:
        bounds = [0] * len(w)

    for _ in range(itern):
        for _ in range(3):
            deltas = [f(delta, *bounds) for f in w]
            maxchange = max(map(abs, deltas[1:]))  # ignore the first delta
            bounds[:] = [b + d for b, d in zip(bounds, deltas)]

            if delta > 1:
                delta *= step_mults[0] / maxchange

            if tols[1] <= maxchange <= tols[0]:
                break

            if delta > 1:
                if tols[0] < maxchange:
                    delta *= step_mults[0] / maxchange
                elif maxchange < tols[1]:
                    delta *= step_mults[1] / maxchange
```

Comment: OK. I don't understand however why users like to downvote questions like these when, again, it's not a lazy question and it can yield answers like yours that are quite informative. Would you consider this to be a -7 point question? Not in my opinion, specially being fundamented as it is.

Comment: upvoted for the nice hack, but I would surely not want to debug such a gem in production

Comment: @DeepSpace not everything has to be production quality. I also mentioned my personal situation, which is computational physics: there's not much debugging in that, we just want to get things working quickly.

Comment: @mariogarcc "there's not much debugging in that, we just want to get things working quickly" That is kind of an oxymoron. You want to get things working quickly, but what would you do when they stop? For example, in this case, when that `for` loop will become an infinite loop? (which does not normally happen in Python)

Comment: @DeepSpace: I wrote this to illustrate what is going on. I'll add a better alternative to show how I usually solve problems like these.

Comment: I understand what you guys are trying to prove, but that doesn't mean there isn't a logic reasoning behind my explanation. `while` loops like these necessarily need a `n += 1` line or similar to work, which is a thing `for` loops do not need, so the latter is faster. Also, `91 * 10**9` microseconds end up being very noticeable indeed, if those 91 microseconds are "per-loop".

Comment: @mariogarcc: those 92 microseconds are **in favour of the `while` loop**, actually. And if I ran the timings again, it'll be a few microseconds in the other direction. Microoptimisations at this level are rarely worth it.

Comment: @mariogarcc At this point we don't even know if you *need* such a solution since you never showed your *actual* problem

Comment: Right, so the conclusion is the best option is to just go with `while` loops, then. Downvotes were unnecessary...

P.S.: @DeepSpace I linked a page to my problem. If you want to see my personal implementation, I can post it in one of the chats.

Comment: @mariogarcc: no, you misunderstand me entirely. The basic bytecode instructions for a `while` loop are slightly more efficient than for a `for` loop. But that only matters if *everything else is equal*, but it clearly isn't. I'm only demonstrating that your blanket `for` loops are faster statement is incorrect, because you are failing to account for all the variable parts in the two constructs.

Comment: Now I'm lost. Is my statement "`while` loops like these necessarily need a `n += 1` line or similar to work" incorrect? Because if it is correct, then the loop has to include that line as well. I can understand that a comparison is faster than a `__next__()` call, and I of course have no problem with this. The problem is the actual implementation, which needs the variable increment as compared to the for loop, so I don't understand what problem people have or what they seem to be complaining about.